# Converting short Python code to C to make it run faster

Tags: python, c, python-2.7

I wrote a bit of Python code to slice text files. But now the text files are very large, making the computations incredibly slow. I would like to convert the code to C and hopefully do the computations a little faster. Could you help me with that? This is my Python code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import 

T = 20 # length of the output files
# Opening a file with paths to the files that need to be sliced
with open('path.txt', 'r') as paths_list:
    for file_path in paths_list:
        with open(file_path.strip(), 'r') as file:
            data = np.loadtxt(file_path.strip())
            t = data[:,0] # the first column: time
            x = data[:,1] # the second column: photon count

            # Using the name of the files as input 
            # to find the time at which the files need to be sliced
            start = file_path.strip() 
            start = start[0:-4]
            start = float(start)

            # slicing the files at the start time
            indstart_data = where(t>start)[0][0]

            # slicing at the end time 
            # which is 20 seconds after the start time
            indeind_data = where(t<start+T)[-1][-1]

            newdata=data[indstart_data:indeind_data,:]

            # using the start time to name the output files
            start = str(start)
            np.savetxt(start, newdata)
```

What it does is, it takes a file with paths to the files I want to slice. These files have a column with time and a column with photon count. The files are named after the the start time where the output files have to start.

The files are sliced, starting at the start time and ending 20 seconds later (T = 20). This slice is saved in the output files which are also named using the start time.

Any help is appreciated! I more or less figured out how to slice the files in C. It's it's mostly the first part of this code that I can't figure out how to convert, so how to go from the file with the paths, to the actual input files and using the name of the files as input.

Also if you guys have suggestions to make it run a little faster, I would really appreciate that! I have a couple of hundred input files most of which are a few GB.

Right now I have this very incomplete code in C:

```
fp=fopen("test.txt", "w");

for (int i = 0; i < unknown_numberoflines; i++)
{
    file = fopen(pathies, "r");

    if (feof(file))
        break;

    /* scan a file */
    fscanf(file, "%Lf %Lf", &(lines[i][0]), &(lines[i][1]));

    /* print contents of file */
    printf("%Lf %Lf \n", lines[i][0], lines[i][1]);
    printf("%i", i);

    /* put certain lines in a new text file */
    if ((lines[i][0]) > 20 && (lines[i][0] < 40))
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%Lf %Lf \n", lines[i][0], lines[i][1]);
    }

    fclose;   
}

fclose(file);
return 0;
```

Comment: "from scipy import " have you tryed running your code?

Comment: I would wager the bottleneck will be the disk, in which case you won't gain much from converting to C.

Comment: Could you explain that? What would be the disk?